# Block specific script tags from website in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to block this Script code with chrome extensions??

```
<script>
  if(document.referrer.indexOf('example.com') === -1) {
     var url = "https://example.com/?beta=1&s=e";
     window.location.href = url;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) might be useful here.